# 1040 NR Line 22 Schedule OI

Tags: united-states, india, non-resident

Line 22 of 1040 NR is  "Total income exempt by a treaty from page 5, Schedule OI, item L (1(e))"

I am a resident of India for tax purposes, and I was not able to identify in the [India-US tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/india.pdf) any clause pertaining to how much income is exempted from US taxation. Can someone help me find this? Also, I don't understand the reference to Schedule OI, item L (1(e)). Are they just stating where the treaty is to be found?

Comment: What is your status in the US? For example, if you are a student or apprentice, article 21 applies. If you are a professor, teacher, or research scholar, article 22 applies.

Comment: I am none of these. Does that mean that nothing is exempt from taxation?

Comment: generally, yes. US income is generally not exempt from US taxation, except for students or interns from certain countries with treaties (and even then, there are usually limits on the amount exempt or time the exemption lasts). You may be able to get a foreign tax credit from India where you are resident.

Comment: How does one claim foreign tax credit?

Comment: @user2371756: You claim it on your Indian tax return, so you won't be taxed again by India for your US income.